# Custom Cell not resizing UILabel's

Tags: ios, storyboard

I'm designing a custom cell on my storyboard and it's not resizing my labels according to its text's size. I'm using this code:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    [titleLabel sizeToFit];
    //[titleLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]]; -- I put this code here just to be sure that awake from nib is working
}
```

Should I implement something else?

Regards!

Comment: at first glance, I wonder why you are both setting line break mode and sizing to fit.

Comment: is it not necessary to call sizeToFit if you want to use multiple lines on a UILabel?

Comment: Never mind, I was thinking you wanted it to stretch width-wize for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `sizeToFit` in `layoutSubviews` method.